# Remove Domain Access fieldset from node forms

Tags: 7, domain-access

I would like to remove the *Domain access options* fieldset from my node forms.

How can I do this? Should I remove is using `hook_form_alter()`?

Comment: A form_alter with $form["fieldset"]["#access"] = FALSE seems right